# MAAS mirrored regions

Tags: server, juju, maas, openstack, high-availability

I've started setting up a MAAS environment.

The basic configuration is pretty straightforward so far except it doesn't seem like mirroring is an option. Rather it looks like the region controller runs only on a single machine and clusters can only join one region. This is an obvious challenge for fail-over.

Basically, what I want is this: Region1 would have Cluster1 and Cluster2. Region2 would have Cluster1 and Cluster2. Cluster1 and Cluster2 would both have Node1, Node2, etc.

Is mirroring something that will be provided by OpenStack once I get to that point of the install?

Is there a cookbook that has a mirroring setup?